# Is it a good idea to filter input before running awk action?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

If I have some input, is it better to filter the data before I run my `awk` action or should I do all the filtering in `awk`?

For example given the following input:

```
$ echo "foo\nbar\nbaz"
foo
bar
baz
```

Should I run:

```
$ echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" | sed 1q | awk '{ print $0 " cats" }'
foo cats
```

Or:

```
$ echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" | awk 'NR == 1 { print $0 " cats" }'
foo cats
```

- Why should I run either one?
- Should I use a different tool?
- What factors should I be considering?
- How can I test those factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, the second option is the better one.

In general, it’s more efficient to minimise the number of utilities in a pipeline. It’s best not to fork (start) unnecessary processes (as in your first example with an unnecessary `sed` process). On the Internet, it’s not hard to find examples of complaints about [useless uses of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

With most modern Unix-like systems<sup>*</sup>, forking is carried out quite efficiently, but it depends on the size of the process being started, e.g, launching `perl` or `python` would be much slower than `sed` or `awk`.

For once-off commands, this doesn’t matter too much – but if your pipeline was inside a loop and being run many multiple times, removing unnecessary process from your pipeline could dramatically speed up total execution time.

#### Specific questions

> Why should I run either one?

If you’re more familiar with the syntax of one over the other, it might be
better for code readability (and maintainability) to use the tool/language
your most familiar with.

> Should I use a different tool?

In this specific case, I wouldn’t think so. Both `awk` and `sed` are
appropriate tools for this kind of job.

> What factors should I be considering?

If you have to process multiple files (e.g., in a loop), then speed/efficiency would be important.

If you’re just processing one large file, every so often, code readability
might be more important.

> How can I test those factors?

You can profile different versions by using the `time` utility, available as shell builtin with Bash – but also as a standalone executable program. E.g. running the two example commands shows that the first example took .012s longer than the second.

```
$ time echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" | sed 1q | awk '{ print $0 " cats" }'
foo\nbar\nbaz cats

real    0m0.056s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.045s

$ time echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" | awk 'NR == 1 { print $0 " cats" }'
foo\nbar\nbaz cats

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Note that profiling benchmarks are affected by system load and other limiting factors so you’d need to repeat this a large number of times to get a true picture of which version is faster than the other.

---

<sup>*</sup>With MS Windows, forking *is* more expensive so minimising the number of processes being started does make a difference when running in environments such as Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to use ***awk***(or ***sed***) tool for such simple cases. A combination of multiple tools would be overcomplicated and often redundant:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | awk 'NR==1{print $0" cats"}'
```

The output:

```
foo cats
```

---

> What factors should I be considering?

Make sure that the needed text processing requires combination of several different tools, otherwise - use the power of one distinct tool

Let's say if I only need to add a certain word before the first word in the input string - it's also easy with ***sed*** tool:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | sed 's/^.*$/& cats/; 1q'
foo cats
```

`echo -e`, `e` flag "enables interpretation of backslash escapes"

---

Anyway, it depends on how complex is your input text and how sophisticated is your text processing rules

Comment: Thank you for the response, the thing I'm curious about is what factors to consider when evaluating the complexity of the input and sophistication of text processing rules. Also please see edit, the input is intended to start on separate lines.

Comment: in your question, the input string is `'foo bar baz'`. You just converted spaces into linebreaks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, please see edit, the point is not converting the spaces to line breaks, it's asking how one should consider breaking up text- filtering and processing.

Comment: @mbigras, see my update

Comment: I don't know why Roman's answer was downvoted as it's essentially correct (and useful). I feel morally obliged to upvote it – only 80 more question to get that Sportsmanship badge :)